# How to compute correlation between two RDDs with same number of partitions (1) but not the same number of element in the partition? using spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want compute correlation between two RDDs series using Spark Scala but i have an exception: `Can only zip RDDs with same number of elements in each partition.` Need your help!

```
val seriesX = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rddFact).collect()
val seriesY = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rddVar).collect()
```

So I want compute correlation:

```
val correlation: Double = Statistics.corr(seriesX, seriesY)
```

Comment: Correlation says if there is a linear relation between corresponding values of X and Y, i.e. between x and y with the same index. If the two series have different size, correlation doesn't make any sense.

Comment: when i print rddFact.length and rddVar.length i have the same number. So I think that the two series have same size.